# Interrupting running queries before closing connection MySQL Python connector

Tags: python, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am running a series of SQL queries through  Python SQL connector that can take too long. I'm using the interruptingcow package to stop the queries that are taking more than 10 seconds. I am then closing the cursor and the connexion when I identify this kind of query in order to try to kill them properly.

But I suspect these queries are still running on the server even when the connection is closed which slows down the running time of the rest of the queries.
Is there a solution to flush all the queries that are running on the server before reopening a connection. Maybe I could keep the connection and cursor open if it's possible.

Here is the part of the code I'm using:

```
from interruptingcow import timeout
import mysql.connector

cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor_open = True

for email in emails:

    if cursor_open is False:
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
        cursor = cnx.cursor()

    query = journey_query.format(email=email)
    try:
        with timeout(10, exception=RuntimeError):
            results = cursor.execute(query, multi=True)
            for result in results:
                if result.with_rows:
                    abc = result.fetchall()[0]
                else:
                    continue
    except RuntimeError:
        cursor.close()
        cnx.close()
        cursor_open = False
        continue

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Apparently they introduced server-side SELECT timeouts starting in MySQL 5.7.4 ([https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/server-side-select-statement-timeouts](https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/server-side-select-statement-timeouts)) This feature might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the oracle article on [Killing threads](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-killing-threads), this will leave the connection open but kill the query that is running.

`cnx.connection_id` is the thread id that is running the queries. [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlconnection-connection-id.html)

```py
cursor.execute('KILL QUERY %s', (cnx.connection_id,))
```